# Getting ActionViewTemplate error in Heroku but not local rails environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am deploying to Heroku and keep getting an error when loading the form to create a new room

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'attractions' for Room)
```

I have added :attractions in permitted params in the RoomsController

```
params.require(:room).permit(:attractions)
```

and this is what the attractions text field looks like in the form

```
<%= form_for @room, html: {multipart: true} do |f| %>
      <label for="textarea2" style="font-size: 17px; color: #0089ec;">Neighborhood Attractions</label>
      <%= f.text_area :attractions, autofocus: true, :placeholder => "What tourist attractions are in your city", :class => "materialize-textarea"  %>
```

This is the migration created to add the attractions field

```
class AddAttractionsToRoom < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        add_column :rooms, :attractions, :text
    end
end
```

and finally in the show page I have this

```
 <div class="col m8 offset-m1 s12">
       <p class="grey-text"><%= @room.attractions %></p>

 </div>
```

Does anybody know why this is happening? Thanks

UPDATE:

So i checked the logs and found the problem is that i made migration errors and rake was aborting before the attractions field is created.

Here is the mess i made:

first i add a city_limit boolean field

```
class AddAmenitiesToRoom < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        add_column :rooms, :city_limit, :boolean    
    end
end
```

then for some reason I forgot I had created the city_limit boolean field and instead thought I had a city string field. So I thought I should rename it to city_limit with this migration

```
class ChangeColumnName < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        change_column :rooms, :city, :city_limit, 'boolean USING CAST(test_type AS boolean)'
    end
end
```

And finally I decided, you know what, I think I need a city string field after all for geolocation so added another migration

```
class AddAcityToRoom < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        add_column :rooms, :city, :string
    end
end
```

Embarrassing, I know. Staying up late coding away is never good. But the problem can be easily fixed by removing this migration,

```
class ChangeColumnName < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        change_column :rooms, :city, :city_limit, 'boolean USING CAST(test_type AS boolean)'
    end
end
```

I just dont know if deleting the migration file is a good idea since I have already run rake db:migrate and there are about 10 other migrations after this one so rake db:rollback is not really an option

Comment: is it working in local?

Comment: Make sure you've run `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: Thanks for the help but I updated my question. Rake was aborting before the migration ran

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps is a problem of static assets.... 
Try to install gem 'rails_12factor'

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

bundle install
```